# Why doesn't these two div widths equal 100%?

Tags: html, css

Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dazakip/u7d59901/

```
.nav {
    float: left;
    width: calc(100% - 75px);
    height: 10px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: green;
}

.checkout{
    float: right;
    width: 75px;
    height: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Specifically this code. Want the two divs to sit next to each other, and remain regardless of resizing. The preview will show what I mean.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a padding-left of 5px, which is taken in account with the calculation. If you remove or calculate the 5px it should be fine!

```css
.nav {
 float: left;
 width: calc(100% - 80px); /* add 5px */
 height: 10px;
 padding-left: 5px; /* or remove padding */
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 background-color: green;
}

.checkout{
 float: right;
 width: 75px;
 height: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 background-color: red;
}


.lol {
 
 height:111110px;
 background-color:grey;
}
```

```html
<body>
 
 <div class="nav">HOME | MENS | WOMENS</div> 
 <div class="checkout">Checkout</div>
 
 <div class="lol"></div>
</body>
```